# OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag is not supported with codec id 12 and format 'mp4 / MP4

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, mp4, fourcc

I was trying to run a repo located [HERE](https://github.com/Pratik08/Vis-DSS). Basically, just targeting `SimpleVideoSummarizer.cc` which uses OpenCV for some basic video processing. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Following is the save part of the code:

```
void SimpleVideoSummarizer::playAndSaveSummaryVideo(char* videoFileSave) {
    cv::VideoCapture capture(videoFile);
    cv::Mat frame;
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0);
    cv::VideoWriter videoWriter;
    if (videoFileSave != "") {
        videoWriter = cv::VideoWriter(videoFileSave, CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), static_cast<int>(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)), cv::Size(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)));
    }
    for (std::set<int>::iterator it = summarySet.begin(); it != summarySet.end(); it++) {
        capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, segmentStartTimes[*it] * frameRate);
        for (int i = segmentStartTimes[*it]; i < segmentStartTimes[*it + 1]; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < frameRate; j++) {
                capture >> frame;
                cv::putText(frame, "Time: " + IntToString(i) + " seconds", cvPoint(30, 30),
                            cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, cvScalar(200, 200, 250), 1, CV_AA);
                if (frame.data) {
                    cv::imshow("Summary Video", frame);
                }
                if (videoFileSave != "") {
                    videoWriter.write(frame);
                }
                // Press  ESC on keyboard to exit
                char c = static_cast<char>(cv::waitKey(25));
                if (c == 27) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    capture.release();
}
```

I pass an `input.mp4` file and specify a `out.mp4` as well. Unfortunately, when the example is trying to save the output video file, it throws errors on the FOURCC:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x44495658/'XVID' is not supported with codec id 12 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v'
```

or another one:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x3234504d/'MP42' is not supported with codec id 15 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
[mp4 @ 0x16bc700] Could not find tag for codec msmpeg4v2 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
```

I tried to change the FOURCC in this part of the code which writes the video, and applied XVID, MJPG, X264, MP42, MP4V. None worked and threw similar errors.

**What is the problem? How to fix it?**

Comment: OpenCV looks to be finicky about which codecs are allowed in which containers. So XVID has to go in AVI even though ffmpeg allows it.

Comment: @Gyan yes it worked! So what codec should go with a `.mp4` container?

Comment: `'H','2','6','4'`

Answer (score 38):

I basically replaced 'MP4V' with 'mp4v' and got rid of the issue. It seems like that the API is case sensitive.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone stranded here due to the same error, to write frames to a `.mp4` output file, use these chars as arguments:

```
cv.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
```

or

```
cv.VideoWriter_fourcc('H','2','6','4')
```

- Depending on the codecs available on your system.
- Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.

---

In your code try replacing

```
CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
```

with

```
CV_FOURCC('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
```

---

I solved my problem with the help of this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/OpenBCI/OpenBCI_Experiment/issues/2#issuecomment-913221647).

If it does not help, consider this post from the [NVIDIA forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/python-what-is-the-four-characters-fourcc-code-for-mp4-encoding-on-tx2/57701/4) and plug in the ASCII number directly in `cv2.VideoWriter()`, without using `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc()`  like this for example:

```
cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', 0x00000021, 15.0, (1280,360))
```

Comment: `cv.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')` was the only one that worked in my case. Thanks, @codingYps.

Comment: It also works with AVI files (in my case, always)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed similar problem on macOS by install **ffmpeg**:

macOS:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use **`'a', 'v', 'c', '1'`** (`avc1`) to request H.264.

ffmpeg is of the opinion that "H264" is an invalid fourcc in an MP4 container.

`mp4v` is not H.264. `mp4v` is the previous compression standard, implemented by DivX/XviD.